# R: Adding row index values as rownames

Tags: r, matrix

I've this matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    0    0
 [2,]    0    0
 [3,]    0    1
 [4,]    1    0
 [5,]    3    2
 [6,]    4    0
 [7,]    0    0
 [8,]    0    0
 [9,]    4    5
[10,]    0    3
```

I want to add the rownames just as numbers like this:

```
   [,1] [,2]
1     0    0
2     0    0
3     0    1
4     1    0
5     3    2
6     4    0
7     0    0
8     0    0
9     4    5
10    0    3
```

I did that manually but If I have too many rows, It would take me too long to do that. Is there any other shorter way to add the row indexes as rownames?

Here is the code:

```
mat=matrix(c(0,0,0,1,3,4,0,0,4,0,0,0,1,0,2,0,0,0,5,3), ncol=2)
mat
rownames(mat)=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10")
```

Comment: `rownames(mat) <- 1:nrow(mat)`

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for very large matrices may i recommend the optimized primitive: `seq_len()`. Here you'd do

```
rownames(mat) <- seq_len(nrow(mat))
```

Comment: Your welcome :) If this answered your question, please mark it as the answer. Thanks!